# angular 4 use component throughout application

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a reusable component and use it multiply times in my application. Also I need to pass different data every time. In this component I want pass data from different component every time. For example a custom modal component and call it from every component I want, and pass it the appropriate data. How I can do this??

Comment: Use the right tags please... Corrected!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it? Just start using your components in the application.

If you want to pass data you can read up on [component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction). You will probably want to use `@input decorators` to pass data into the components.